# Uniform convergence of a series depending on $\alpha ,\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Find all $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2\alpha}+n \sin x\cos\frac{2\pi n}{3}}{\sin^2x+n^2x^{2\beta}}$$
converges uniformly on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}.$

<s>I would say that pointwise convergence works only for $\beta>\alpha$ and *|x|*>1 because of the exponential function.</s>

**EDIT:** No exponential functions.

Comment: You may have posed the problem incorrectly. It reads as if we have uniform convergence on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: @zhw You're right, I edited the question. I'm not native speaker, so sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: By the way, "exponential function" usually means something like $2^x$ Also note that if $x<0$ you have trouble raising $x$ to arbitrary real powers. I would look at uniform convergence on $(0,\infty).$

Comment: You can rewrite this as $$A\sum_n \frac {B +n\cos (\frac{2\pi}3n)}{C + n^2}$$ where $A, B, C$ depend on $x$ Assuming it converges pointwise (haven't investigated that), the terms are bounded on finite intervals, which should make it uniformly convergent.

Comment: $\beta >\alpha$ is a necessary condition: put $x=m\pi$ in the general term of the series and let $m \to \infty$. (If the series converges uniformly then the general term must tend to 0 uniformly).